# Reverse Stack elements C++

Tags: c++, stack

I have this reverse method on my stack that reverses the elements inside the stack to a tmpStack. I want to know how to assign tmpStack to my original stack. I did not find a way to assign my original stack to that value so it can show up when I use print and not just print tmpStack. My problem is in the last lines.

```
template<class T>
void stack<T>::reverse(){

    T item;
    stack<T> tmpStack;

    while (empty() == false)
    {
        item = stack<T>::pop();
        tmpStack.push(item);
    }


    stack<T> = tmpStack;


}
```

Comment: Why don't you reverse *in place* elements of the current stack? Something like: `for (int i=0; i<top/2; i++) swap(element[i],element[top-i-1])`. Creating an secondary stack for this is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `operator=` is working correctly:

```
*this = tmpStack;
```

*Edit:*

As Toby hinted to correctly: Since C++11, the better way is

```
*this = std::move(tmpStack);
```

The difference: in your concrete case, none, as you do not provide a move assignment operator. But if you do so, the latter one would be called instead.

```
Stack& operator=(Stack&& other)
{
    // You do not copy the data any more here, but SWAP!
    // Swapping assures that, if *this has data allocated
    // other will clean it up correctly for you.
}
```

With such an assignment operator (and an appopriate move constructor, keyword [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)), you get more efficient code as you save one step of data allocation and destruction (move instead of copy).

Comment: If you had a working move-assignment operator, `*this = std::move(tmpStack)` would normally be preferable.